# Android studio emulator: WARNING System.cpp

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have the following warning in Android Studio Event Log when starting android studio emulator: 
What might be the problem here?

> 09:44 Emulator: emulator: WARNING: System.cpp:1139: Ignoring invalid
>   parameter detected in function: 0000000000000000 file:
>   0000000000000000, line: 0, expression: 0000000000000000

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I got this error after updating my SDK Tools and a related code change. I fixed the error by going into Tools>AVD Manager, selecting the device emulator I was working with and doing wipe data.

Comment: Yep, this did it for me as well.

Comment: Same here, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Look ! I just Ctrl + Alt + Del(or Delete , depending on your own keyboard) , then right click the "adb.exe *32" with "end process tree" , so "Android SDK built built for x86 (mobile)" shown again . BTW , I do above when I had already start the "AVD Manager" and its Virtual Devices .
You should be carefully deal with it and my principle is start fixing it from the most simple and easy way since I got previous mistake and it has annoyed me so